# How to cancel a task from different class

Tags: c#, task

I want to cancel a task started by one class from some other class. Below is an example program where i have two classes and want to cancel the task from different class. Cancellation token doesn't seem to work.

```
namespace threadingiwthcancel
{
    class ThreadExample
    {
        public async Task PrintSomething(CancellationToken token)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Cancel requested");
                    break;
                }
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                i++;
            }

        }
    }
    class Cancel
    {
        public void cancelTask()
        {
            CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
            source.Cancel();
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken token = source.Token;
            callasyncmethod(token);
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            Cancel c = new Cancel();
            c.cancelTask();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async void callasyncmethod(CancellationToken token)
        {
            ThreadExample te = new ThreadExample();
            await te.PrintSomething(token);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try out answer , let me know it worked for you or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cancellation token doesnt seem to work.

The reason for failure is that you are creating a **different** `CancellationTokenSource` and calling `Cancel` on it.  Sadly, no other operations will be notified and so your original task continues.

> I want to cancel a task started by one class from some other class

Be sure to pass the *original* source to it:

```
class Cancel
{
    CancellationTokenSource _source;

    public Cancel (CancellationTokenSource source)
    {
       _source = source;
    }

    public void cancelTask()
    {            
        _source.Cancel();
    }
}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = source.Token;
        callasyncmethod(token);
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        Cancel c = new Cancel(source); // pass in the original source
        c.cancelTask();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: yes that worked out. The reason for this post is we are designing an WPF app with multiple pages each with view model. In one page after a button click we call a async function(doing some background work) which will also show a loading screen. In the loading screen we have a button to cancel the operation. Loading is screen is tied to a one base view model and previous screen to another view model and we want to cancel that async operation started from previous screen. Passing token as param is not possible as each view creates a view model object for data context

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do like that than you need to pass object of CancellationSoruce to you cancel method in other class , do not create new CancellationSoruce

```
class Cancel
{      
 public void cancelTask(CancellationTokenSource source )
    {
        source.Cancel();
    }
}
```

in main

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken token = source.Token;
            callasyncmethod(token);
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            Cancel c = new Cancel();
            c.cancelTask(source );
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

---

or can do like this

```
  class Cancel
    {   
        private readonly CancellationTokenSource source;
        public Cancel(CancellationTokenSource source)
        {
          this.source = soruce;
        }   
        public void cancelTask()
        {
            source.Cancel();
        }
    }
```

and in main

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken token = source.Token;
            callasyncmethod(token);
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            Cancel c = new Cancel(source );
            c.cancelTask();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```